# Laravel 5 Eloquent relationship: getting the data

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Get Data in `Laravel 5`.

**My tables:**

*Users:*

```
-id
-username
-password
```

*Group:*

```
-userid
-groupname
```

**My models:**

*Users(model):*

```
-hasOne(Group)
```

*Group(model):*

```
-belongsTo(Users)
```

If i do this:

```
$userdetails = \App\Users::find(1);
```

I only get user info. I need to do this to get the group:

```
$group = $userdetails->group;
```

It doesn't seems elegant to have two different variable to send to the view. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use eloquent `with()`.

```
$userdetails = \App\Users::with('group')->find(1);
```

you could access the group attributes like `$userdetails->group->groupname`